# How can I insert a keyframe at curve between two keyframes

Tags: animation

How can I insert a keyframe at this point of the curve on all channels at the cursor location, I have made offset and I want to delete the keyframe before frame 0 .. when I select all and press I and insert keyframe nothing happens
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add a keyframe to multiple f-curves at once, you have to select all of those f-curves.  You only have one selected in your screenshot.

Go to the left of what you have in your screenshot and find the list of f-curves.  Here's my list from an animation that simply moves an object in Y and Z:

[image: f-curves]

Select the individual F-curves that you want to add the keyframe to.  Unselected curves will be white, selected will be yellow, if you use the default theme.  Here I have selected all three curves.  (Left click to select, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> left click to add to selection.)

Move the cursor to the frame where you want to add the keyframe. (Your screenshot looks like you're already there.)

With the mouse somewhere in the graph, type <kbd>I</kbd>.  This menu should appear:

[image: Popup menu showing All Channels option]

left click on *Only selected channels* or type <kbd>O</kbd>.

EDIT:  in response to a comment fixed the menu entry to pick.

EDIT 2: In response to a comment that this doesn't work:

It is possible that you have an active Keying Set that is preventing you from adding keyframes to some curves.  You can check this by going to the left side of the Top Bar of the Timeline editor and clicking the *Keying Menu*.  A popup like this will appear:

[image: Keying popup from the time line]

If there is text in the left highlighted box, it means that you have an *Active* [Keying Set](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html).  Keying sets only allow new keys to be added to certain F-curves.  To disable the Active keying set, click the button highlighted on the right.

Returning to the graph editor, another reason might be that you have one or more F-curves *locked*.  You can't add keyframes to locked curves.  You can check this in the list of F-curves on the left side of the graph.  The red box in the next image shows a locked F-curve. The other F-curves in the image are unlocked:

[image: F-Curves showing one locked and 2 unlocked.]

If you do have an Active Keying Set

Comment: Actually, pressing I and choosing "All Channels" inserts keyframes on all channels even if you didn't select them. If you disabled the "Only Show Selected" option in the graph editor so that all F-curves of all objects are displayed, "All Channels" not only inserts keyframes even on unselected curves of the selected object, but also on all curves of unselected objects. All visible curves.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. However when I follow your steps and insert a keyframe on all channels still nothing happens as shown in the picture https://i.imgur.com/Ry0yM16.png

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: @Ibrahim  In that case, you have a setting that limits what keyframes you can insert, either the preferences setting suggested in another answer, or you have keying sets enabled and the other f-curves aren't in the keying sets.

Answer (score 1):

In Blender preferences-Animation-keyframes, un-tick "Only Insert Needed"
[image]